# Error usando PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

El error es el siguiente:

> Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fecth() in /home/ubuntu/workspace/redsocial/classes/gestores/ManagerSeguidor.php on line 73 Call Stack: 0.0004 236840 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/redsocial/index.php:0 0.0040 322128 2.

Y mi funcion es esta:

```
function isFollower($id, $idPerfil){
    $sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM follow WHERE idPerfil = :idPerfil AND idFollow = :idFollow;';
    $params = array(
        'idPerfil' => $idPerfil,
        'idFollow' => $id
    );

    $res = $this->db->execute($sql, $params);
    $statement = $this->db->getStatement();

    if($res && $row = $statement->fecth()){ // EN ESTA LINEA
        return $row[0];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El error me lo da en el if y no entiendo porque, he hecho esto miles de veces, pero ahora no logro ver mi error. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es un error de sintaxis puesto que es **`fetch`**. Primero la `t` y luego la `c`. Ojo, en `$res` ya deberías tener una instancia del statement a la que puedes aplicar cualquiera de los métodos de lectura, no le veo ningún sentido al uso de `getStatement`

Comment: Buah, muchas gracias de verdad, no lo veía.

Comment: Recomiendo que leas la documentación en el Manual sobre PDO, para que lo uses de una manera óptima. Lo digo por la forma en que veo que usas el statement y por el método fetch que usas. PDO es una clase muy completa con métodos para casi todo. Por ejemplo en este caso, puesto que es una consulta con `COUNT` puedes usar `fetchColum` para obtener el dato esperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error principal es debido a un error de sintaxis, ya que el método se llama `fetch`,  no <s>`fecth`</s>.

Aunque quiero aprovechar para sugerirte algunas mejoras:

1. El método `prepare`, como indica la documentación, devuelve un objeto `PDOStatement`, al cual le puedes aplicar cualquiera de los métodos `fetch` para obtener los resultados. Por tanto, no veo el sentido de usar el método `getStatement`, el cual parece ser una *re-invención de la rueda.* Normalmente el orden es el siguiente:

   a. Preparas la sentencia, y al prepararla, obtienes una referencia al objeto `PDOStatement`
     b. Aplicas el `execute` a ese objeto
     c. Aplicas cualquiera de los métodos `fetch`  a ese objeto.
2. PDO es una clase bastante completa, sus métodos `fetch` son de una riqueza enorme, como para aplicar el más adecuado en cada caso. Por ejemplo aquí, dado  que tu consulta devuelve una sola columna, convendría usar [`fetchColumn`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

Visto esto, tu código debería funcionar así:

```
function isFollower($id, $idPerfil){
    $sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM follow WHERE idPerfil = :idPerfil AND idFollow = :idFollow;';
    $params = array(
        'idPerfil' => $idPerfil,
        'idFollow' => $id
    );

    /*Mandas a preparar la sentencia, prepare devuelve un objeto PDO Statement*/
    $stmt=$this->db->prepare($sql);
    /*Usas el mismo objeto para el execute, pasándole los parámetros*/
    $stmt->execute($params);

    /*
      *Podemos usar una operación ternaria para evaluar $stmt
      *Si es verdadero, obtendremos el valor obtenido con COUNT
      *Si es falso, obtendremos 0
    */
    $resultado= ($stmt) ? $stmt->fetchColumn() : 0 ;
    return $resultado;
}
```